# Facebook retargeting pixel parameter options for redirect?

Tags: facebook, ads

I've been looking for a list of url parameters that can be attached to a Facebook "website custom audience".

```
<img src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=123456789&ev=PageView" width="1" height="1">
```

Specifically, is there a URL parameter I can add that will 302 redirect to another tracking pixel after the Facebook cookie has been placed?  Something like:

```
<img src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=123456789&ev=PageView&redir=https://www.tracker.com/pixel?id=abc" width="1" height="1">
```

I know other advertising platforms support this method -- but haven't been able to find anything along those lines for FB yet.

Bonus points if you know of any other parameter options that can be added to customize the pixel drop.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not support this.

Can you use two images?